# NHibernate without reflection?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection, orm, mapping

We are currently using NHibernate for accessing our database.

We have database, which store a "configuration". We have the notion of "revision", meaning that every table in our database has a revision, and when we make any change(even a small one), every field in our database get duplicated(except the changes that will not be the same).

The goal is to be able to switch easily from one revision from another, and be able to delete one configuration and still be able to switch from an earlier or older revision.

It implies that when we change the configuration, we make a lot of writing in the database(and other application will have to read also it).

This steps can take a very long time(5-10 minutes, we have a lot of table), compared to 10-20 seconds to store it in xml.

After spending some time in analysis, we have the impression that NHibernate has to make a lot of reflection to map database to c# objects(using our hbm.xml files).

My questions:

1. How does NHibernate read/write properties in every object, with reflection, right?
2. Does it make reflection at every write, or is there some optimization(cache, ...?)
3. Is there a possibility to avoid this "reflection"? Like having some class created/compiled on build(like it's possible with entity framework)?
4. If I've a working NHibernate model, is there something I can do to "tune" the DB access, without changing the database?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: that's an interesting question but it's very broad and hard to answer succinctly.  maybe break it down a little.  I'd also sounds like this auto versioning of everything could really kill the performance of your app.

Comment: My only question at the end is mostly the question "3.", all other questions are in my opinion only required to be able to response to this questions. I'm open to suggestion but I think it will only put off the complexity of the final question.

Yeah I would totally agree that the versioning has a lot of down sides, but we cannot do without it(and this is a big feature, already working for 2 years ;) ).

Comment: Are you using triggers to duplicate the data?

Comment: I'm asking as I doubt reflection is your bottle neck here.  Have you profiled what is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by triggers? You mean the DB ones or is there a trigger mecanism with NHibernate? In both case: no. Mostly because for every table, sometimes we will create a completly new row, sometime delete, sometime update, and for our 200+ tables, it will makes a LOT of cases to handle, and we also want to avoid to give to much business intelligence to the database to improve the maintainability. A colleague has done some profiling, and he was seing a lot of time spent with NHibernate, but hard for him to know exactly in what part of NHibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assuming it is relection.  I would strongly recommend downloading (as a free trial at least) [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) to see what is taking NHibernate so long.  Or some other database profiler.

If I had to guess it was the number of database updates that is required here but I wouldn't guess about performance without getting some metrics first ;)

For instance it might be that you need to increase your batch size in NHibernate if you are doing a lot of small updates in one session, which can be done in your nh config file

```
<property name="adonet.batch_size">300</property>
```

Comment: This seems to be very interessting, I will try both tomorrow. But what information will NHProf give me? Except the time for every request? I've the impression that I will only be able to check if I've not huge requests produced

Comment: Hi, I used NHProf(but I can't make him connect to our SQL Anywhere database apparently). I also tried to set the BatchSize (in the `Dialect` implementation: `DefaultProperties[Environment.BatchSize] = "300";` I don't know if it's the right place, but it didn't change anything. I've a lot of alert(currently 17'000 and growing about this: http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf/learn/alert/TooManyDatabaseCalls I'm currently looking on what is `MultiQuery` but for now didn't found a good reference

Comment: this is exactly what nhprof is good at, breaking down what your application is doing.  17000 alerts would suggest 17000 calls in one session?  That is an awful lot and that's not going to be good in any ORM.  that said you might look at http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/06/24/bulk-processing-with-nhibernate/

Comment: Yeah, was what I was telling when saying that we were having an huge database to insert. But the other option that we have is to have two DB access layer, one with an ORM, and the other without, which was not very pleasant and effective. We are currently reviewing another option, to not use an ORM, but this will take a lot of efforts, and what I need is to optimize the most I can before we will do this big changes(~3 months of works). Thank for the link I will read this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoir Reflection, but it is not a problem. NHibernate use a lot of Reflection to prepare and emit dynamic code. Generated code is faster than static code because msil allow you more thing than c#.

If implementation of reflection usage seems to be your issue you can juste extends NHibernate but write a byte code provider.

Personnaly, proxy generator, usertype and property accessors can be faster than builtin implementation.

Generally, performance issue caused by Nhibernate is often :

- missing fetching
- precision data causing unwanted update
- bad mapping (structure or simply datatype)
- bad database/datatable configuration
- bad commit strategy (flush mode for exemple)